# How to create a table with dates in sequence between range in Hive?

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, calendar, hiveql

I'm trying to Create a table with column date, And I want to insert date in sequence between Range.

Here's what I have tried:

```
SET StartDate = '2009-01-01';
SET EndDate = '2016-06-31';

CREATE TABLE DateRangeTable(mydate DATE, qty INT);


INSERT INTO DateRangeTable VALUES (select a.Date, 0
from (
    select current_date - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) AS a where a.Date between '2019-01-01' and '2016-06-30');
```

Comment: did above solution work ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the similar one:

select date_add(t.f1, t.start_r - pe.i) as date_range from  (select '2022-01-01' as f1,datediff('2022-01-07','2022-01-01') as start_r,0 as end_r) t lateral view posexplode(split(space(start_r - end_r),' ')) pe as i,s;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple answer:

```
set lower.bound.date='2023-05-01';
set upper.bound.date='2023-08-31';

with date_seq as(
select posexplode(split(space(datediff(${hiveconf:upper.bound.date},${hiveconf:lower.bound.date})),' '))
)
select date_add(${hiveconf:lower.bound.date},pos) from date_seq;
```

`datediff(...)` provides number of days between two dates, `spaces(...)` created specific number of spaces, the  `split(...)` function splits the data by single space `(' ')`. The `posexplode(...)` converts row elements into columnar format with `pos` as index and space as value.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need VALUES keyword when using INSERT ... SELECT.

Working example:

```
set hivevar:start_date=2009-01-01;
set hivevar:end_date=2016-06-31;

CREATE TABLE DateRangeTable(mydate DATE, qty INT);

with date_range as 
(--this query generates date range
select date_add ('${hivevar:start_date}',s.i) as dt 
  from ( select posexplode(split(space(datediff('${hivevar:end_date}','${hivevar:start_date}')),' ')) as (i,x) ) s
) 

INSERT INTO TABLE DateRangeTable
select d.dt, 0 qty
  from date_range d
 where d.dt between '2019-01-01' and '2016-06-30');
```